# Access to a VMware VM Ubuntu server via SSH from the internet with public IP

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vmware, ip

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 which is fully functional inside my home network. The server is a VM inside VMware Workstation Pro and I can access it via SSH using its IP address 192.168.42.135

Now, the VM is connected to the internet via VMware NAT and, clearly, it can't be accessed outside my network via SSH.

I would like to know if is there a way to connect to it via SSH using a public IP and how do I assign it to my server

Comment: is this VMware Workstation or PLayer on your computer?  Or is this VMware ESXi?

Comment: @ThomasWard Workstation Pro. Updated the question

Comment: Make sure you open Windows Firewall to listen for port 22 connections if you haven't already.  Otherwise the NAT to the VM might not work.  As for Public IP, you need to configure *that* on your router at the border of your network to forward port 22 to the IP of the system running VMware Workstation.  AND you need to use the public IP your router sees for connectivity (you can get that from https://ifconfig.co)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to configure port forwarding in two places to make this work.

1. You need to configure your ISP gateway device to forward incoming connections to some port to the laptop running workstation. 22 is the default ssh port, but the gateway may not let you use that. You can use any other port, but you’ll need to convey that information to anyone you wish to allow to connect. Let’s say you pick port 9022 to listen on, and you set that to connect to port 8022 on your windows system running workstation.
2. Now, you need to set up port forwarding in VMware workstation, such that inbound connections to port 8022 in windows gets connected to port 22 in your ubuntu VM. You also need to be sure windows firewall permits inbound connections on 8022. For ease of use, you could also set up a host name with a dynamic dns provider like noip.com. Then you would just need to share the dynamic dns host name and port to people.

As an aside, there is an option in the settings of the virtual machine where you can easily configure VNC access. You would select "Edit virtual machine settings" and in the Options tab, find "VNC Connections." For that feature, you have to select a port on the host system to use, and then when you connect from some remote VNC client, you would use the host IP and the port you've chosen to connect. Note that the host system is the system that is running VMware Workstation Pro.

[image: edit VM settings dialog]

They don't have a shortcut like this for SSH though, so you'll have to use the virtual network editor to do this. The VM itself will connect to the virtual network VMnet8, which in your example is 192.168.42.0/24. You would edit that network, and again configure an external host port to use, which you would configure to connect to port 22 on your virtual machine's IP. Note that you'll have to ensure that your host OS allows connections on that port, and it isn't blocked by any OS firewall.

[image]

Comment: I would add that you probebly want to get a static public IP from your ISP if you want other poeple to connect using `DNS`. Also alot of home routers come with their own firewall. Make sure your ports are open there too

Comment: Thanks. I added the suggestion to use dynamic dns, as that should be an option for most places.  A static IP would also work, though that may be harder to come by.